Automatically expand `Post task execution logs` log group in Airflow
Is there a way to automatically expand grouping of log lines? When I am debugging a task failure, I often need to look at the Post task execution logs to find out why a task failed. Manually expanding that log group every time I'm debugging is tedious.
It would be great to have a feature to either:

Automatically expand specific log groups
Disable log grouping for specific log groups

It looks like the post execution group start is printed on this line of code.
Related issue: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/41198
